# I have got an error On SQL query - PHP-SQLWarning: mssql_query(): message: Incorrect syntax near '='. (severity 15)

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I am running this php code with sql query but it keeps showing this error and i couldn't find where the mistake is? Can you help please.*THANKS IN ADVANCE*

> Warning: mssql_query(): message: Incorrect syntax near '='. (severity 15)
>
> Warning: mssql_query(): General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server (severity 15)
>
> Warning: mssql_query(): Query failed

I have this on my **user.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['refresh'])){
    $mssql_real = db_connect_real();
    $sql = "UPDATE TOP(1) click_users_phones SET pin_failed = 0, status = 1, pin_blocked_time = NULL WHERE phone_num = $phone_num";
    mssql_query($sql, $mssql_real);
}
```

I have this on another php file

```
<form action="user.php" method="post">
    <button class="#" name="refresh">Refresh</button>
</form>
```

Comment: [This](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-query.php) might enlightment you about using `mssql_*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update this statement

```
$sql = "UPDATE TOP(1) click_users_phones SET pin_failed = 0, status = 1, pin_blocked_time = NULL WHERE phone_num = $phone_num";
```

to

```
$sql = "UPDATE TOP(1) click_users_phones SET pin_failed = 0, status = 1, pin_blocked_time = NULL WHERE phone_num =".$phone_num;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL statement should be like

```
UPDATE TOP(1) A SET pin_failed = 0, status = 1, pin_blocked_time = NULL 
FROM click_users_phones A WHERE phone_num = ''
```

**Note:**
But you should remember that SQL never guarantee you the order. So If you are updating the TOP 1 ,then you should provide the `ORDER BY` in the select. So that you will update the correct record.

Comment: Shakeer Miza thank you for your answer.  Should all update code  be in double quotation marks Like this? "UPDATE ,,,, phone_num = ' ''  ".???

Comment: Sorry. I dont know the `PHP`. But I found a syntax error in your SQL code which I bring to your notice. I think `$sql = "UPDATE TOP(1) A SET pin_failed = 0, status = 1, pin_blocked_time = NULL 
FROM click_users_phones A WHERE phone_num =".$phone_num;`  seems correct as Ramesh suggested. @OstonovSherzod